# Python regex to match only if `=` is present

Tags: python, regex

I have this data:

```
{{Character
| Title=Jhiqui
| Image=Jhiqui.png
}}

{{Ala|a;a}}
```

I want to write a regex on python that matches the content inside the `{{}}` for the first data but nothing for the second.

I have this `\{\{(.+?)\}\}` that with DOTALL matches the content of both lines. I want to add something to the regex that requires for the content inside `{{}}` to contain one or more `=`.

How can I do that?

The regex given by @heemayl doesn't match the following text:

```
{{Character\n| Title = Jon Snow\n| Image = Profile-JonSnow-707.png\n| Season = [[Season 1|1]], [[Season 2|2]], [[Season 3|3]], [[Season 4|4]], [[Season 5|5]], [[Season 6|6]], [[Season 7|7]], [[Season 8|8]]\n| First = "[[Winter is Coming (episode)|Winter is Coming]]"\n| Last = \n| Appearances =\n| Aka = Aegon Targaryen<br>Lord Snow<br>The Bastard of Winterfell<br>King Crow<br>[[The Prince That Was Promised]]<br>The White Wolf\n| Status = [[:Category: Living individuals|Alive]] <small>(resurrected)</small>\n| Titles = [[Warden|Warden of the North]] <br>[[King in the North]] <small>(formerly)</small><BR>\n998th [[Lord Commander of the Night\'s Watch]] <small>(formerly)</small>\n| Place = [[Tower of Joy]] <small>(birthplace)</small><br>[[Winterfell]] <small>(raised)</small>\n| Allegiance =  [[House Stark]]<br>[[House Targaryen]] <small>(by pledge)</small><br>The [[Night\'s Watch]] <small>(formerly)</small>\n| Family = \n| Lovers = [[Daenerys Targaryen]]<br>{[[Ygritte]]}\n| Religion = [[Old Gods of the Forest]]\n| Culture = [[Northmen]]<!--Please do not add "Valyrian" to his culture. Despite his blood, he was raised a Northman, without any knowledge of his heritage. This has been discussed and clarified, so insisting on it will be considered fanon and dealt with accordingly-->\n| Actor = [[Kit Harington]]\n| Age = 23 in Season 8<ref>Jon is roughly the same age as Robb Stark, and they were both born near the end of Robert\'s Rebellion - which in the novels was 15 years before the beginning of the narrative, so they were both about 14. In the TV version, the rebellion was 17 years ago, making Jon and Robb 16 in Season 1. Seven years pass in the TV series by Season 8.</ref>\n|Birth = Shortly after [[Robert\'s Rebellion]], [[Timeline#Robert\'s Rebellion|281 AC]]\n|Death = [[Timeline#Season 5 - 302 AC|302 AC]]<br>\nStabbed to death by his own men in the [[Mutiny at Castle Black]] <small>(later resurrected)</small>\n|DeathEp = [[Mother\'s Mercy]] <small>(soon after resurrected)</small>\n|Father = Biological:<br>\n{[[Rhaegar Targaryen]]}\n----\nAdoptive:<br>\n{[[Eddard Stark]]}\n|Mother = {[[Lyanna Stark]]}\n|Siblings = Paternal half-siblings:<br>\n{[[Rhaenys Targaryen (daughter of Rhaegar)|Rhaenys Targaryen]]}<br>\n{[[Aegon Targaryen (son of Rhaegar)|Aegon Targaryen]]} (son of Elia)\n----\nMaternal cousins raised as half-siblings:<br>\n{[[Robb Stark]]}<br>\n[[Sansa Stark]]<br>\n[[Arya Stark]]<br>\n[[Bran Stark]]<br>\n{[[Rickon Stark]]}<br>\n}}
```

Which should be getting matched, and is getting matched with my simple regex that doesn't check for the `=`.

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
\{\{([^}]*=[^}]*)\}\}
```

in multi-line mode.

- `\{\{` matches `{{` literally
- `[^}]*` matches zero or more characters that are not `}`, then `=` is matched literally
- `[^}]*` again matches zero or more characters that are not `}` and `\}\}` matches `}}` literally at the end
- The content inside `{{..}}` will be available in the only captured group

---

```
In [125]: text = '''{{Character 
     ...: | Title=Jhiqui 
     ...: | Image=Jhiqui.png 
     ...: }} 
     ...:  
     ...: {{Ala|a;a}}'''                                                                                                                                                                                    

In [126]: re.search(r'\{\{([^}]*=[^}]*)\}\}', text, re.M)                                                                                                                                                     
Out[126]: <re.Match object; span=(0, 48), match='{{Character\n| Title=Jhiqui\n| Image=Jhiqui.png\n>

In [127]: re.search(r'\{\{([^}]*=[^}]*)\}\}', text, re.M).group()                                                                                                                                             
Out[127]: '{{Character\n| Title=Jhiqui\n| Image=Jhiqui.png\n}}'

In [128]: re.search(r'\{\{([^}]*=[^}]*)\}\}', text, re.M).group(1)                                                                                                                                          
Out[128]: 'Character\n| Title=Jhiqui\n| Image=Jhiqui.png\n'
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. It does work for some cases, but I have included a case in which it doesn't work (and I managed to identify others that don't work either). Any ideas why?

Answer (score 2):

I am pretty sure you even want to actually do something with the values, so go ahead and write a small parser for it to be able to further work with it afterwards:

```
import re
from parsimonious.grammar import Grammar
from parsimonious.nodes import NodeVisitor

data = """
lorem ipsum

{{Character
| Title=Jhiqui
| Image=Jhiqui.png
}}

lorem ipsum dolor sit amet

{{Ala|a;a}}


"""
# the regex
rx = re.compile(r'\{\{.+?\}\}', re.DOTALL)

# the parser
class SomeVisitor(NodeVisitor):
    grammar = Grammar(
        r"""
        expr        = lpar tag ws? attr+ rpar
        attr        = delim ws+ word ws? equal ws? word ws?
        tag         = word+
        word        = ~"[.\w]+"
        delim       = "|"
        equal       = "="
        lpar        = "{{"
        rpar        = "}}"
        ws          = ~"\s+"
        """
    )

    def generic_visit(self, node, visited_children):
        return visited_children or node

    def visit_attr(self, node, visited_children):
        key = visited_children[2]
        value = visited_children[6]
        return (key.text, value.text)

    def visit_tag(self, node, visited_children):
        return node.text

    def visit_expr(self, node, visited_children):
        _, tag, _, attr, _ = visited_children
        return {tag: dict(attr)}


# invoke it
sv = SomeVisitor()

for m in rx.finditer(data):
    try:
        tag = sv.parse(m.group(0))
        print(tag)
    except:
        pass
```

This yields

```
{'Character': {'Title': 'Jhiqui', 'Image': 'Jhiqui.png'}}
```

Comment: That is an interesting approach, I think it is worth checking it out +1

Answer (score 1):

Something like this would work:

```
{{([^}=]+=.+?)}}
```

https://regex101.com/r/qhT7K0/1

Comment: `.` in a delimited string will never work in 100% cases. If there is `{{....}} {{...=....}}` the match will be the `{{....}} {{...=....}}`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks, I hadn't considered swapping the order of those data sets. How does my update look?

Comment: It won't match  `}` before `=`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Oh okay, I see what you mean. However, OP does not mention the possibility of this edge-case so I am just gonna proceed with the assumption that my regex is fit for the use-case presented.

Answer (score 1):

You can use negated character class and `=` inside captured to make sure it matches only when there is `=`

```
\{\{([^=]*=.*?)\}\}
```

[image]

[`Regex demo`](https://regex101.com/r/2nCInh/2/)